# combo-box-drop-drop-list-remembers last "x" choices, width is settable to less than contents

Tags: jquery, combobox, drop-down-menu

before developing it ourselves, we are looking for a combo-box-drop-down-list with the following optional features:

1. combo-box can be programmatically turned on/off
2. drop down remembers the last x (x set by program) user selections and displays them at the top of the drop down list, so that the user does not have to scroll through a very long list.
3. drop down list WIDTH is settable programmatically so that it is a fixed width that is less wide than the contents when the list has not been clicked on. But when the user clicks on the drop down, the drop down list shows the full width of the contents.
4. Able to specify an abbreviation in the drop down list after the user has selected their choice. For example, this will be very useful for time zone management.

We want to use jQuery if feasible. So far our searches have been inconclusive for any widgets that have all of these features, so we thought to ask here first.

Here is an example of how we would use the widget:
There are over 400 time zone cities world wide across 26 time zones that a user of ours will need to be able to chose from. We want the user to be able to type in a string that we will search for as an alternative to scrolling the list.

In this case we want to remember their last 5 TZ selections so that they are at the top of the drop down list.

For example: IST is displayed in the drop down when the widget is just sitting there.
But when they click on the drop down you see [(GMT + 5.5) India Standard Time, IST, Chennai, India]

Answer (score 0):

We used Infragistics , Telerik controls few years back , they were pretty good.
Nowadays Component one is also very nice. Check the free demo on their websites to match your requirements.

Otherwise you can buy on of that products and customize to your requirements by overwriting the functionalities.